# How do you prove $I_n - A$ is invertible when A is symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been struggling to prove that if $A$ is a $nxn$ symmetric matrix with **every eigenvalue $|\lambda_i|<1$** then $I_n-A$ is invertible.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: $|\lambda_i| < 0$?  Do you really mean that?

Comment: In general, $I-B$ is invertible if and only if $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $I-B$, if and only if $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$. (and this doesn't require $B$ to be symmetric)

Comment: Solved, it was $|\lambda_i|<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use theorem that eigenvalue  for polynomial of matrix is this polynomial of original eigenvalue of the matrix.
Symmetric matrix has only real eigenvalues then $-A$ has only positive eigenvalues. If you additionally add $I$ to $-A$ you have all eigenvalues greater than 1. Therefore $I-A$ is invertible.

Comment: The solution was given for $\lambda_i<0$, but of course the way of dealing with the problem  after author's edit is similar also for $\vert \lambda_i \vert  < 1$